# Дескриптор JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться со следующим:

На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) указано,что атрибуты `writable`, `enumerable`, `configurable` по умолчанию `false`;

Но почему тогда:

```
var person = {name};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person,'name'));
19:20:38.695 VM130:2 {value: "", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если создавать свойство через `defineProperty`, оно получит именно те атрибуты, которые указаны по умолчанию:

```
var person = {};
Object.defineProperty(person, 'name', {});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person,'name'));

> {value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

В [стандарте ECMA 262 пункт 11.1.5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) есть описание, когда в каких случаях какие атрибуты ставятся; в частности:

```
The production PropertyAssignment : PropertyName : AssignmentExpression is evaluated as follows:

Let propName be the result of evaluating PropertyName. 
Let exprValue be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression. 
Let propValue be GetValue(exprValue). 
Let desc be the Property Descriptor{
    [[Value]]: propValue, 
    [[Writable]]: true, 
    [[Enumerable]]: true, 
    [[Configurable]]: true
}
Return Property Identifier (propName, desc).
```